# How to convert FxCopReport format in sarif format?

Tags: c#, fxcop, sarif, microsoft-code-analysis

Running microsoft code analysis using MSBUILD creates xml file which is in FxCopReport format. How canit be converted in sarif format ?

Comment: What code analysers are you using. Do they have an option to output in your desired format?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73651251/how-do-i-force-msbuild-to-create-sarif-files-on-codeanalysis

Comment: I am using Microsoft code analysis using "msbuild project.sln /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=output.xml" syntax from command prompt